# Application Logs on Cloudfoundry don't show up

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have a problem with my application logs on my Cloudfoundry deployment.

I've deployed Cloudfoundry in a something minimized design based on the tiny-aws deployment of https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/cf-boshworkspace.
I further minimized the deployment and put everything from the VMs "api", "backbone", "health" and "services" together on the api-machines.
So I have the following VMs:

- api (2 instances)
- data (1 instance)
- runner (2 instances)
- haproxy (1 public and 1 private proxy)

Cloudfoundry version is 212.

The deployment itself seems to work. I can deploy apps and they start up.
But the logs from my applications don't show up when I run
"cf logs my-app --recent"

I've tried several log-configurations in my spring-boot-app.

- standard without modifications which should log to STDOUT according to spring-boot documentation
- exlicitly set a log4j.properties file which was configured to log to STDOUT as well
- a log4j-2 configuration for logging on STDOUT
- a spring-boot configuration which logs to a file

In the last configuration, the file was created and my logs was shown when I ran "cf files my-app log/my-app.log"

I tried to debug where my logs are lost, but I couldn't find something. 
The dea_logging_agent seems to run and has the correct NATS location configured, the dea itself too.
Loggregator seems to run well on the api-host too and seems to be connected to NATS too.
So my question is: In which locations should I search to find out where my logs go?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you deploy ETCD as well. The dea_logging_agent will check with ETCD to see which loggregator/doppler server is currently alive.

Comment: Yes. Etcd is deployed also. It seems to work, But it looks like the logs are Not getting to the dea_logging_agent